# calling parent constructor with more parameters than the child's one in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
class Parent{
public:
Parent(string a, int i, int j, int k): name(a), num1(i), num2(j), num3(k){}
~Parent(){}
...
//other member functions
...
protected:
string a;
int num1, num2, num3;
};

class Child : public Parent{
public:
Child(string a, int i, int j): Parent(???){}  //how should I initialise the base class?
~Child(){}
....
//other member funcitions
....
}
```

In the above classes, parent got more data members than the child, but many of the member functions will be inherited from the parent. I don't know whether there is a way to call a parent constructor which have more parameters than the child constructor.

Comment: Give the parameter a default value.

Answer (score 3):

The `Child` can provide whatever values it needs for the additional parameters, eg:

```
class Child : public Parent {
public:
    Child(string a, int i, int j): Parent(a, i, j, 12345){}
    ...
};
```